# Alarms and Events

Tags: opc-ua

I have worked on Alarms and Events in OPC Classic. I was wondering if there is an equivalent option in OPC UA. I am using Siemens S71512 CPU, which has got a built-in OPC UA Server.

Regards,
Nandgate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic OPC had Alarms and Events, OPC UA has Alarms and Conditions.

This is specified in part 9 of the OPC UA specification. You can get it [here](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture/part-9-alarms-and-conditions/)

Currently few OPC UA Servers and Clients supports it.

Comment: Could you please mention which OPC UA Servers support AE, so that I can order it.